# Password protecting some sub folders with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a folder structure like this...

```
- folder
    - folder01
        - public
        - open
        - closed
    - folder02
        - public
        - open
        - closed
    - folder03
        - public
        - open
        - closed
    - folder04...
```

These main folders are sequentially numbered and dynamically created with three sub folders. I need to password protect each of the 'closed' folders with the same long password. However I do not want to have to manually add in the .htaccess into the 'closed' folder each time a new main folder is added as this could get tedious and what happens if I forget!

Basically I am looking for a solution where these 'closed' folders will be protected by .htaccess but the 'public' and 'open' folders would not.

Comment: Only manually adding in the .htaccess each time

Comment: *Hm...* interesting question I found. Hard to say, but storyboarding this in my head right now, I'd do something like: 1) create one `.htaccess/htpasswd` file and put it somewhere. 2) use include for it. 3) create a script that will scan over all those folders (glob or scandir or other similar function) and include the file. Sounds doable.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will look into that option. I must say its had me a bit stumped!

Comment: You're welcome. (I take it that ^ was aimed at me) ;-)

Comment: Yes, I just needed some pointers for the right direction. I will give it a go!

Comment: 10-4, glad to see I was of help. Try something out and we'll also be happy to help if you run into a snag. Remember to use error reporting when in development.